# How do I use the *really* secret unlocks?

Tags: bionic-commando-rearmed

[image: Cryptic Message]

There are a total of three unlocks that give a similar message when viewed in the database.  I have no idea what this message is talking about.

Are these unlockables for a different game or something?  How do you use/enable them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [a few things](http://mycheats.1up.com/list/cheat/3163679/bionic_commando/xbox_360) that are unlocked in the "Bionic Commando" remake by doing certain things in "Bionic Commando: Rearmed."  The BC Retro Outfit is one of them.  You have to have a BC: Rearmed save with this unlocked in order to use the skin in the other game.

The unlocks are:

> - BC Retro Outfit - Complete BC: Rearmed.
>  - Prototype Weapon - Get the Albatross icon from the last level of BC: Rearmed
>  - Purple Matrix - After getting all the Yashicis, find the Purple Matrix item in Area 00

Comment: Ah... figures.  I have the other game for Xbox 360, and rearmed for PC.  Rats.